# do Google Map Markers have to be added in ViewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

This is my code for `ViewController.m`: So far, I've been loading a list of Map markers from a database in `viewDidLoad`. I want to add a marker and have it appear on the map, but the marker never shows up until I close the view and open it again.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <GMSMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView;

 @end
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Getting My Location
//Instantiate a location object.
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager setDelegate:self];

//Set some parameters for the location object.
[locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy: kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
NSLog(@"created locationManager");

// Google Map View
_mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;
_mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topLayoutGuide.length + 10, 0, self.bottomLayoutGuide.length, 0);

    /* Setting Up Markers */
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    [self addMarkers];
}
```

an IB Action is called (and definitely gets called) to add a new Marker, but the Marker does not show up on the map. I've tried this in `ViewWillAppear` and others, but the marker is not added. I'm starting to think markers can only be added in `ViewDidLoad`...is this true?

```
    -(IBAction)unwindtoRoot:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
NSLog(@"unwindToRoot");
//[self addMarkers];

CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.729358, -73.998301);
    GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
    marker.title = @"Kopi Kopi";
    marker.map = _mapView;
}
```

Comment: Also, wondering if the best way to do this is to keep a small array of Markers locally and just add to the array as well as the database, when adding a new marker